# issue in picking video and playing it

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

i being trying to play video from lib but i cant figure out what im doing wrong i have tried many things and its not showing any kind of error my code is below

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:mediaType];

    NSLog(@"%@",url);

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];


    /* Create a new movie player object. */
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    if (player)
    {
               /* Specify the URL that points to the movie file. */
        [player setContentURL:url];





        /* Add a background view as a subview to hide our other view controls
         underneath during movie playback. */


        CGRect viewInsetRect = CGRectInset ([self.view bounds],
                                            kMovieViewOffsetX,
                                            kMovieViewOffsetY );
        /* Inset the movie frame in the parent view frame. */
        [[player view] setFrame:viewInsetRect];

        [player view].backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

        /* To present a movie in your application, incorporate the view contained
         in a movie player’s view property into your application’s view hierarchy.
         Be sure to size the frame correctly. */
        [self.view addSubview: [player view]];


        [player setCurrentPlaybackRate:0.5];
        [player play];
    }







        // Register for the playback finished notification
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserver: self
         selector: @selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
         name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
         object: player];



}



// When the movie is done, release the controller.
-(void) myMovieFinishedCallback: (NSNotification*) aNotification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *playerr = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:playerr];
    [playerr stop];
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    [playerr autorelease];
}
```

what happen is first `presetModelViewController` is getting displayed then i can shows videos which are in my lib i can select one of them but when i choose video then it shows my grey color view and nothing else and my video is not getting played.

If you could find any errors in my code and can help me with this then it will be great help.

Comment: can you send the log of  NSString *mediaType.

Comment: let me show that to you

Comment: it prints public.movie

Comment: i guess this is where the issue is it should be whole url to lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through the below link will help you with your existing issue and also implementation.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios

```
 NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:videoURLString]; 
 MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]   
 initWithContentURL:videoURL]; 
 [moviePlayer prepareToPlay]; 
  [moviePlayer play]; 
  [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
```

Comment: they are doing with MPMoviePlayerViewController which is not helpful for me because i want to use the property of mpmoviecontroller like slowing video, playing video is speed and all the other property thats why i need to use this approach

Comment: let me try ill let you you what happen

Comment: its ok spider any other suggestion

Comment: i have made my comment as an answer and edited above try using this and don't forget to check , " CGRect viewInsetRect = CGRectInset ([self.view bounds],
                                            kMovieViewOffsetX,
                                            kMovieViewOffsetY );"
what this is returning

Answer (score 0):

```
This is what solved my problem thanks to spider1983 

   - (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel: (UIImagePickerController *) picker {

        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    }

    // For responding to the user accepting a newly-captured picture or movie
    - (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
     didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

        NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];


        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

        // Handle a movie capture
        if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge_retained CFStringRef)mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0)
            == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

            NSString *moviePath = [[info objectForKey:
                                    UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];




            NSLog(@"%@",[info objectForKey:
                         UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]);


        /* Create a new movie player object. */




            MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];



        if (player)
        {
                   /* Specify the URL that points to the movie file. */
            [player setContentURL:[info objectForKey:
                                   UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL]];


            CGRect viewInsetRect = CGRectInset ([self.view bounds],
                                                kMovieViewOffsetX,
                                                kMovieViewOffsetY );
            /* Inset the movie frame in the parent view frame. */
            [[player view] setFrame:viewInsetRect];

            [player view].backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

            /* To present a movie in your application, incorporate the view contained
             in a movie player’s view property into your application’s view hierarchy.
             Be sure to size the frame correctly. */
            [self.view addSubview: [player view]];



            [player prepareToPlay];
            [player setCurrentPlaybackRate:0.5];
            [player play];
        }







            // Register for the playback finished notification
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
             addObserver: self
             selector: @selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:)
             name: MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
             object: player];
        }


    }
```